# Xcode: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context ERROR in UISlider

Tags: swift, uislider

```
extension ViewController: SliderDelegate {



func susimBackgroundValueChanged(slider: UISlider) {
    
        slider.isContinuous = false
    
        slider.setValue(
            value: round(slider.value * 8) / 8,
            animated: true,
            completion: { (getValue) in
                UIView.transition(
                    with: self.scrollView,
                    duration: 0.25,
                    options: .transitionCrossDissolve,
                    animations: {
                    self.scrollView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(imageView.image?.size.height ?? 
                        0 * getValue)
                    },
                    completion: nil
                )
            }
        )
    
    }
}
```

I added a closure to "setValue" function using an extension.
setValue function is a Built-in function in UISlider.

```
extension UISlider {

    func setValue(value: Float, animated: Bool, completion: @escaping (_ getValue: Float) -> 
        Void) {
        self.setValue(value, animated: animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(value)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why I get an "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error 
Please save me

Comment: On what line do you get the error and out of curiosity I have to ask why you do `0 * getValue`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I guess `0 * getValue` is a typo, there should be  `0 : getValue()`

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov That would create a compiler error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message and position is misleading, the problem is in the mixing of types in this line:

```
self.scrollView.frame.origin.y = CGFloat(imageView.image?.size.height ?? 0 * getValue)
```

Convert `getValue` to `CGFloat` to resolve this:

```
self.scrollView.frame.origin.y = imageView.image?.size.height ?? 0 * CGFloat(getValue)
```